# Given that $x(\theta)=5\cos \theta,y(\theta)=5\sin \theta,z(\theta)=\theta$

Tags: calculus

Given that $x(\theta)=5\cos \theta,y(\theta)=5\sin \theta,z(\theta)=\theta$

$L(\theta)$ is the arclength at the point $P(x(\theta),y(\theta),z(\theta))$ and $D(\theta)$ is the distance from origin to $P$.If $L(\theta_0)=\sqrt{26}$ then $D(\theta_0)=?$

My attempt:$$D(\theta_0)=\sqrt{25+\theta_0^2},L(\theta_0)=\sqrt{26}\theta_0=\sqrt{26}\implies \theta_0=1$$

Hence $D(\theta_0)=\sqrt{26}$

Is this correct?or I am doing something wrong?

Comment: Don't you get $D(\theta_0)=\sqrt{25+\theta_0^2}$?

Comment: Oh yes sorry thanks

Comment: Answer still same

Answer (score 0):

Im not really confident about my answer and i seem to have done it without calculus but ill give it a shot,

I remember learning that arclength of a circle is (calling s length)

$s = r\theta \therefore$

$\sqrt(26) = r\theta$

with r beting distance you can use distance formula which is $r = \sqrt{x^2 + y^2 + z^2}$ so then

$$
\sqrt{26} = \theta * \sqrt{25\cos^2(\theta) + 25 \sin^2(\theta) + \theta^2}
$$
square both sides

$
26 = \theta^2(25(\sin^2(\theta)+\cos^2(\theta))+\theta^4
$

using trig identity $\sin^2(x)+\cos^2(x) = 1$

$
26 = 25\theta^2 + \theta^4
$

$$
\theta = \pm 1
$$

Which seems pretty logical unless im missing something